# Parse.com - retrieve text from .txt

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve some text from a file that I uploaded to Parse, but anything that I try seems not to work. I tried using the example that Parse gave, but I couldn't make it work. Can somebody help or explain to me how I can do that?

This is the example:

```
PFFile *applicantResume = anotherApplication[@"applicantResumeFile"]; 
NSData *resumeData = [applicantResume getData];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the data back to a string, try this.

Save

```
PFObject * anotherApplication = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"Resumes"];
NSData *data = [@"Working at Parse is great!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"resume.txt" data:data];
anotherApplication[@"applicantResumeFile"] = file;
[anotherApplication save];
```

Open

```
[anotherApplication fetchIfNeeded];
PFFile *applicantResume = anotherApplication[@"applicantResumeFile"];
NSData *resumeData = [applicantResume getData];
NSString* dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resumeData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Received string: %@", dataStr);
```

Don't forget that in practice, it's best to use 'getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:' , 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock:' , and 'fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:'

A note on blocks:

```
NSLog(@"Will Run 1st: %@", reflex.description); // will be null
[applicantResume getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSString* dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    reflex.description = dataStr;
    NSLog(@"Will Run 3rd: %@", reflex.description); // will contain string.
}];
NSLog(@"Will Run 2nd: %@", reflex.description); // will be null
```

Comment: Thanks Logan it work but when I try to use "getDataInBackgroundWithBlock" I dont get anything in the TextView that I want to show it. Can you please see the code

Comment: That code should be working fine for you @filoX, where and when are you accessing the dataStr? Make sure it's within the blocks, see my edits. In My answer.

Comment: Also it appears that I have answered your original question if it's working for you. Make sure to accept answers if they're correct as opposed to leaving questions unresolved.

Comment: I'm accessing it outside NSLog(@"Will Run 3rd: %@", reflex.description); and it contain the string but it doesnt appear in the TextView. Now Im trying trying to use it here NSLog(@"Will Run 1st: %@", reflex.description);  and use something like                 Detail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataStr];
 to get the text but when i click in a cell i get the data of the cell that i click before

Comment: How are you updating the text view? Whatever your textView is, you should update its .text property if 'description' is a textView property of 'reflex' then set reflex.description.text = dataStr

Comment: I tried it but when is inside the if it doesnt work. I get the text in the NSLog but not in the TextView. When I use PFFile *applicantResume = object[@"applicantResumeFile"];
NSData *resumeData = [applicantResume getData];
NSString* dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resumeData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
reflex.description = dataStr; everything work fine.

Comment: what is reflex.description?  It's probably working fine because when you do it that way the system doesn't move on to the next step until its finished with the data.  Anything that depends on reflex.description existing must wait until the data has been retrieved in the block before it begins. --> What is reflex.description what is reflex, and what does its property 'description' represent?

Comment: reflex is a var name Reflexion *reflex = [[Reflexion alloc] init]; and description is a property @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;... I try Detail = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; and then reflexion.description = Detail; and it work but it doesnt give the the data right. When i click the first cell it doesnt show anything but when i click another cell it show me the data of the cell that i click before

Comment: It sounds like the problem is somewhere else.  If it's working the first way then the second way should work fine as well.  I can't really do more without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate all your help. I wish i have a way to show you. But why is better to use getDataInBackgroundWithBlock?

Comment: We use blocks because when you're downloading a file, in your case a .txt, it takes more time, particularly depending on network.  Any code executed after [getData]; will not start until getData has finished downloading all of its data. This means that your entire UI is frozen and your application is stuck until that file can get the data.  By using getDataInBackgroundWithBlock, we send that code to a background thread that runs independently.  We send the block with it so it knows what code to execute once it's finished downloading the file.  This allows UI & Main thread to continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
PFFile *applicantResume = object[@"applicantResumeFile"];
NSData *resumeData = [applicantResume getData];
NSString* dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resumeData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
reflex.description = dataStr;
```

It workы

When I use getData it doesnt

```
PFFile *applicantResume = object[@"applicantResumeFile"];
[applicantResume getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSString* dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        reflex.description = dataStr;

    }
}];
```